# Почему не срабатывает php в Visual composer?

Tags: php, wordpress, visual-composer

Пробовал вставить php-код через HTML-box в Visual Composer, не срабатывает.

Как вставить php-код на страницу WordPress, созданную с помощью плагина Visual Composer?

Comment: Закрывальщики мои дорогие, @MSDN.WhiteKnight и иже с ним, вы прежде чем жмакать на кнопку, прочтите мой ответ, данный 2 дня назад, отдайте себе отчёт в том, что вы не понимаете сути вопроса, а потом уж что-то делайте.

Comment: @KAGGDesign, к сожалению, в текущем виде вопрос больше похож на поиски [супер-кнопки](http://button.dekel.ru/). Если вы действительно что-то поняли из такой формулировки, пожалуйста, дополните это сообщение.

Comment: @mymedia я поправил вопрос, не знаю, насколько он стал понятнее тем, кто не работал с Visual Composer. Ну, а тем кто работал, вопрос был ясен с самого начала: есть разные блоки для контента в Visual Composer, но ни один из них не позволяет вставить php-код. Ближайший кандидат, по логике, html-блок, но и через него не получается. С чем автор вопроса и пришёл.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

php не будет работать ни в текстовом блоке, ни в html, ни как-либо ещё. Контент перед выводом на экран фильтруется, там никакого php-кода быть не может.

Чтобы сделать правильно, есть несколько способов.

Создайте свой шорткод в functions.php и добавьте вызов шорткода типа

```
[my-shortcode]
```

в текстовый блок. Именно в текстовый, в html-блоке Visual Composer он работать не будет!

Создайте свой шаблон страницы, присвойте его данной странице и управляйте выводом контента самостоятельно.

Используйте плагин для добавления php-кода. Но, по факту, эти плагины работают через шорткоды.

Так что мне кажется, что первый способ наиболее простой и правильный.